# Segmentation faulting in assignment

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, c-strings

I'm currently learning C and I came from java. Our assignment asked us to count strings from either a file that could be added or it asks for the user to input a string. We just started using pointers and i looked up the different reasons why segmentation faults happened but I have no idea how to check for which issue it is. I initialized all my pointers to NULL but it still didn't work and from what i read that was the most common reason why a segmentation fault happens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int debug = 0;

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    extern char *optarg;
    extern int optind;
    FILE* infile = NULL;
    int c, err = 0; 
    int lflag = 0, sflag = 0, count = 0; //flags and count
    char *shortWord = NULL, *longWord = NULL; //variable for shortest and longest word
    int shortest = 100, longest = 0; //longest char 100, shortest 0
    char *string = NULL;
    char *pch = NULL;
    static char usage[] = "usage: %s [-l] [-s] [filename]\n";

    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "ls")) != -1)
        switch (c) 
        {
            case 'l':
                lflag  = 1;
                break;
            case 's':
                sflag = 1;
                break; 
            case '?':
                err = 1;
                break;
        }

    if (err) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, usage, argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    //checks for file and then runs loop for word count
    infile = fopen("myfile.txt","r");
    if (infile != NULL)
    {
        fgets(string, 100, infile);
        pch = strtok (string, " ,.-");
        while(pch != NULL)
        {
            count++;
            if (strlen(pch) > longest)
                longWord = pch;
            if (strlen(pch) < shortest)
                shortWord = pch;
            pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.");
        }
    } 
    //else, asks for string
    else
    {
        printf("Enter your string: \n");
        fgets(string, 100, stdin);
        int len = strlen(string);
        count = len;
        pch = strtok ( string, " ,.-");
        while(pch != NULL)
        {
            count++;
            if (strlen(pch) > longest)
                longWord = pch;
            if (strlen(pch) < shortest)
                shortWord = pch;
            pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.");
        }   
    }

    //following lines compute value based on arguments
    if(lflag == 1)
    {
        printf("Longest word is %s", longWord);
    }
    if(sflag ==  1)
    {
        printf("Shortest word is %s", shortWord);
    }

    printf("Word count = %.2d\n", count);

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: What do you think the purpose of `int argc` that is passed into `main()` might be?

Comment: Suggest you use a debugger. That is the right tool for this and you will benefit from learning to use it.

Comment: "initialized all my pointers to NULL". Despite what you think you read, that is not the way to fix seg faults. *Accessing* NULL pointers is a common reason for seg faults. And that's exactly what value your `string` variable is.

Comment: i googled how to debug and im debugging, it said the issue is in the use of fgets() but im not sure what the issue is

Comment: The issue is you don't understand basic C memory management. I really suggest you pause coding and systematically go through a C book or tutorial. You have set `string` to NULL and then try to write to it. This is very basic stuff and it is counter productive to continue until you really understand it.

Comment: You cant use `fgets` on NULL pointer, you need to use `malloc` to allocate memory, or change `char *string` to `char string[100]`.

Answer (score 1):

Their are some issues in your code:

- You initialized `string` to `NULL`, then used it as an input buffer for `fgets()`. `fgets()` reqiures a pointer to an array of chars, either declared on the stack or dynamically allocated with [`malloc(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc). You can set an input buffer such as `char string[100]`.
- `fgets()` must be checked, as it returns `NULL` when unable to read a line.
- Your delimiter for `strtok()` is not accounting for the `\n` character appended by `fgets()`. You can either remove this newline, or include it in the delimter. If you want to include it in the delimeter, make sure your delimiter is `" ,.-\n"`.
- You could create function which parses your input with `strtok()`, as this would allow your `main()` to be shorter and reduce the repetitiveness in the code. An example function prototype could be `void longest_shortest_words(char line[], char **longest, char **shortest, size_t *word_count);`, whereby you pass the longest, shortest words along with the number of words back to `main()` via pointers. You could also just store the longest and shortest words in a 2D array or array of pointers.
- You should also explicitly check that your file was opened correctly. Something like this should be included:

  ```
   infile = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
   if (infile == NULL) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file\n");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
  ```
- When checking `opt`, checking `?` as a character in your switch statement is not right. Instead of:

  ```
  case '?':
      err = 1;
      break;
  ```

  Use `default`, which covers any other invalid option entered. Here is how you can use it:

  ```
  default:
      fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s [-l] [-s] [filename]\n", argv[0]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  ```
- Checking `sflag` and `lflag` at the end is not enough. You should check if `longWord` and `shortWord` are not `NULL`.

Here is some example code which demonstrates these points:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define LINESIZE 100

void longest_shortest_words(char line[], char **longest, char **shortest, size_t *wordcount);
void print_output(int lflag, int sflag, char *longword, char *shortword, size_t wordcount);
void remove_newline(char line[]);

int main(int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    FILE *infile;
    char line[LINESIZE] = {'\0'};
    int opt, sflag = 0, lflag = 0;
    size_t wordcount = 0;
    const char *optstr = "ls";
    char *longword = NULL, *shortword = NULL;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, optstr)) != -1) {
        switch(opt) {
            case 'l':
                lflag = 1;
                break;
            case 's':
                sflag = 1;
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s [-l] [-s] [filename]\n", argv[0]); 
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    /* Checking if file is in directory */
    infile = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
    if (infile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* checking if line exists in file */
    if (fgets(line, LINESIZE, infile) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No line found in file.\n");

        printf("\nEnter string instead:\n");
        if (fgets(line, LINESIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
            remove_newline(line);
            longest_shortest_words(line, &longword, &shortword, &wordcount);   
            /* checking that longWord, shortWord and word_count are valid */
            if (longword != NULL && shortword != NULL && wordcount > 0) {
                print_output(lflag, sflag, longword, shortword, wordcount);
            }
        }

    /* file has line, do stuff with it */
    } else {
        remove_newline(line);
        longest_shortest_words(line, &longword, &shortword, &wordcount);
        print_output(lflag, sflag, longword, shortword, wordcount);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

/* function for printing output, can be improved */
void print_output(int lflag, int sflag, char *longword, char *shortword, size_t wordcount) {
    if (lflag) {
        printf("Longest word: %s\n", longword);
    }

    if (sflag) {
        printf("Shortest word: %s\n", shortword);
    }

    if (wordcount > 0) {
        printf("Word count = %zu\n", wordcount);
    }
}

/* function for removing newline, and checking that input hasnt exceeded limit */
void remove_newline(char line[]) {
    size_t slen;

    slen = strlen(line);
    if (slen > 0 && line[slen-1] == '\n') {
        line[slen-1] = '\0';
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nToo many characters in input.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

/* function which parses line, and saves longWord and shortWord in pointers */
void longest_shortest_words(char line[], char **longword, char **shortword, size_t *wordcount) {
    char *word = NULL;
    const char *delim = " ,.";

    word = strtok(line, delim);
    if (word != NULL) {
        *longword = word;
        *shortword = word;
        *wordcount = 1;
    }

    while ((word = strtok(NULL, delim)) != NULL) {
        (*wordcount)++;
        if (strlen(word) > strlen(*longword)) {
            *longword = word;
        } else if (strlen(word) < strlen(*shortword)) {
            *shortword = word;
        } 
    }
}
```

**Note:** The code shown above can be improved, it is just to show you another approach to your problem.